# Android custom action bar is not showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes

My parent theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar and i have add 
 in manifest file and create a custom style.xml for a action bar with a different color but instead of all, Action bar is not visible what should i do? I am using android studio and lolipop version.

style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

</style>
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#800000</item>
</style>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<application`enter code here`
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen`enter code here`Activity"
```

Comment: Can you post your Code for Reference?

Comment: To avoid being downvoted , you're advised to post the relevant code snippet of what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Maria `ActionBarActivity` jo code post kayo.. and Custom Action Bar's xml jo bhi..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found solution by

1. Adding support libraries:

[image]

2. Extending AppCompatActivity class
3. Adding code to build.gradle

buildTypes {

```
    debug {

        minifyEnabled true
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
```

Now its working f9.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use *Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar* and create Toolbar layout in main layout. Bind toolbar in activity and

**setSupportActionbar(toolbar);**

Read toolbar section from here: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `styles.xml` to define a custom `ActionBar`, you should use `themes.xml` as documented in [Android Official guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Example taken from [Android development's Official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>

<!-- general styles for the action bar -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

In your manifest file, you can apply the theme to your entire app:

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" ... />
```

Or to individual activities:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" ... />
```